# SetFocusable method or Focusing Components Java

Tags: java, swing, methods, jpanel, focusable

I came across this code:

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public Board() {
        setFocusable(true); 
    }
}
```

What exactly does `setFocusable(true)` do to the JPanel object? What is the notion of a component being focused?

Based on the Java API, this method is located in the Component class, the super class of JPanel. The method description states "Sets the focusable state of this Component to the specified value. This value overrides the Component's default focusability." This description sounds way too technical and high-level jargon for me (who just finished a Java class in the summer). Sometimes, I think these method descriptions were not written for all people with different levels of knowledge of Java. May someone explain the method description in layman's terms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `focusable` flag indicates whether a component can gain the focus if it is requested to do so. The JPanel component is focusable by default, so nothing will be changed when you set it to `true`.

A component that is not focusable can not gain the focus.

**An example**

Let's say you have implemented a dialog with several text fields and you want the user to enter some text. When the user starts typing, one text field needs to have the focus of the application: it will be the field that receives the keyboard input.

When you implement a focus traversal (a convenient way for the user to jump from one text field to the next, for example by using the `tab` button), the user can "jump" to the next text field. The application will try to gain the focus for the next field to prepare it to receive text. When the next field is not focusable, this request will be denied and the next field will be tested. For example, you wouldn't want a label to get the focus because you cannot enter text into it.

The focusable flag is set to `true` by default in the `Component` class. When you construct an object derived from the `Component` class (for example, when you construct your `JPanel`), the constructor of the `Component` class is called and sets the default focusable flag to `true`.

Derived classes that wish to override this default can call the method `setFocusable` to change that default, like you did in your example.

Note that setFocusable does not set the focus in itself, it just gives the ability to potentially gain the focus to the component.

Comment: I do not understand what you are stating. It still sounds way too technical. I do appreciate the reply. Why would one bother giving a component focus as opposed to not giving it one?

Comment: @Nicholas I updated the answer. I hope this example will be clearer. Normally, you would give a component the ability to gain the focus if you need to be able to do something with it. Note that setFocusable does not set the focus in itself, it just gives the ability to potentially gain the focus to the component.

Comment: Now the example makes it more clear for me now that I read how it is applied in a certain situation. Thanks! I'm going to test this method on JTextFields.

Answer (score 0):

`setFocusable()` is actually a method from the `Component` class in Swing.

```
public void setFocusable(boolean focusable)
```

It lets the component (in your case, `JPanel` which *extends* `Component`) have the power of getting focused. It doesn't actually set the component to be focused, it just indicates if the component can be focused or not, which is determined by the boolean parameter passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setFocusable(boolean n)`,  it´s mainly used to activate or deactivate the focus event (component of the graphical user interface that is selected to receive the input) of the view, both in the tactile / mouse mode, and in the keyboard (cursor) mode.